# Looping through an array and appending a variable with the results

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have small bash script that I've written to search through a folder, pull out a list of files that don't match a specific criteria and assign them to an array. I'm then looping through that array and outputting the contents to the stdout. What I want to do is to append each of those results to a variable which I then want to use later in the code. I'm struggling to find any info on how to do this. It seems like it should be super simple, an equivilent of an echo append type of thing but I've found zero examples online. I want something like: $list = $list + $addition

Here's what I have so far. It's 95% finished say for this last piece.

```
    #Declare the array
    array=()

    #Search for any files that are not mp4's. Exclude temp files also.
    while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
      array+=("$REPLY")
        done < <(find "$movies_dir" -type f -not -name "*.mp4" -not -name "*.srt" -not -name "*.db" -not -name "*.tmp" -not -name "*DS_Store" -not -name "._*" -print0)

    #Create an empty variable to assign the list of movies to
    movie_list=""

    # Loop through array pulling out each movie found    
    if [ ${#array[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
      for i in "${array[@]}"
        do
          movie="${i##*/}"
          echo -n "$movie\n"
        done
    fi
```

As you can see from the above code, this will output all movies as one long string seperating each filename with \n (which I plan to use later in a Slack alert). With that in mind, this is the reason I need to assign the string of text to a variable. I want to be able to use it in my Slack notification.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to achieve the above?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to put the output from a command in a variable? You can use `var=$(your command here)`. The command can be a `for` loop.

Comment: `list+=" $addition"` is what it sounds like you want (concatenate `" $addition"` to the end of `list` until you run out of additions -- but note, `list` will be a string, why not make it a separate array?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question (& why it's difficult). In general, you can append to a string variable with `var+=addition`. In this case, the only tricky thing is that you want to append a variable *and* a newline, and those are tricky to do with the same quoting mode (double-quotes around the variable, and ANSI mode `$'\n'` for the newline). But you can mix quoting modes in a single string, so something like this should work:

```
movie_list=""
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
      movie_list+="${i##*/}"$'\n'
done
```

(Note that the `if` is not needed, since if the array is empty the loop won't run at all.)

There are other ways of doing this that avoid even having an explicit loop, like using `printf` with the `-v` option (output to a variable):

```
if [ ${#array[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    printf -v movie_list '%s\n' "${array[@]##*/}"
else
    movie_list=""
fi
```

(Here, note that `[@]##*/` expands to all elements of the array, with `*/` removed from *each one individually*.)

Or you could use a `[*]` expansion of the array, which mashes all elements of the array together separated by the first character of `IFS`, which you can change to newline:

```
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
movie_list="${array[*]##*/}"
IFS=$saveIFS
```

One difference with this one is that it doesn't put a newline at the end, just in between elements. But if you use `echo` to print it, that'll append its own newline at the very end.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm not sure why that solution wasn't apparent at the time (trying to write code at 2am probably didn't help). The truth is, my bash script experience is very much a work in progress. This solution did the trick however to thanks for taking the time to write it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a newline delimited list of your files, this can be entirely handled by `find` this way:

```sh
find \
  "$movies_dir" \
  -type f \
  -regextype egrep \
  -not -iregex '.*\.(mp4|srt|db|tmp|_.*|DS_Store)$' \
  -printf '%f\n'
```